# What's the fastest way to find a route in JS?

Tags: javascript

I am writing a tiny router to just route paths like `/user/info` without any special regex or variables in the string. My current implementation just looks like

```
let routes = {
  user: {
     path: "/user",
     routes: {
         info: {
             path: "/user/info",
             routes: {}
         }
     }
  }
};
```

It then basically treats itself as a linked list and finds object by object name, like `routes["user"]["info"]`; Is there some faster way to do routing that I don't know of? I cannot find anything.

Comment: `routes["user"]["info"]` is undefined in your example

Answer (score 0):

In the given code `routes["user"]["info"]` is undefined.

Suggestion: You can create a `map` for the lookup.

first look for "users" and then its route "info".

Answer (score -1):

I guess no one really understood my question. Anyway, it appears that the fastest way to find a "thing", ie a route such as `/user/add`, in JS is to

1. Use a switch statement of strings
2. Use an if statement of strings
3. Use a switch statement of numbers
4. Use an if statement of numbers
5. Use a map of strings **(wow!)**

All of the 5 methods above are the same speed. The fact that a map is as fast as a switch statement of raw strings is amazing. Using object reflection, as known, is unbearably slow. Hooray for whoever created the map! It's also surprising that using numbers with object reflection is really, really slow. Maybe because each number has to be converted to a string key? Not sure.

Anyway, use a map!

Here is my [js perf](https://jsperf.com/js-router/1)

[It also seems to scale](https://jsperf.com/map-router/1)